# c# HtmlAgilityPack: HtmlNode какая нода текущая

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Предположим, имеется такой html код

```
<td width="12%" height="78"><font face="Arial" size="3">
  <p align="right">Ignacio-Blanco</p>
  <p align="right">Fruitland Coal</p>
  </font><p align="right"><font face="Arial" size="3">La
  Plata</font></p></td>
```

Выбираю td ноду

```
HtmlNode tdNode
```

и пытаюсь XPathoм выбрать значения всех тэгов `<p>`

```
tdNode.SelectNodes(".//p/text()")
```

Выводит:

- Ignacio-Blanco
- Fruitland Coal

Т.е значение La Plata потеряно. (такое чувство, как будто применяю XPath относительно первого `<font>`

Пытаюсь пройтись таким XPathом:

```
..//p/text()
```

Он мне выводит какую-то кучу левых значений впридачу.
Такой вопрос:
Если у нас есть HtmlNode и мы применяем к нему XPath, то корневой нодой (точка) будет считаться сам экземпляр HtmlNode или первый наследник?
И как мне выбрать ВСЕ ноды `<p>`, относительно корневой ноды, независимо от того, насколько они глубоко "вложены"?

Answer (score 1):

Запрос XPath составлен неверно.

Запрос `.//p/text()` будет забирать текстовые значения тега `<p>` вне зависимости от уровня вложенности. Значение "La plata" же не берется, потому что это текстовое значение тега `<font>`.

Чтобы брались и те, и другие текстовые значения, нужно отталкиваться от другого элемента, к примеру, если код только такой:

```
   <td width="12%" height="78"><font face="Arial" size="3">
   <p align="right">Ignacio-Blanco</p>
   <p align="right">Fruitland Coal</p>
   </font><p align="right"><font face="Arial" size="3">La Plata</font></p></td>
```

то подойдет запрос:

```
//text()
```

Чтобы выбрать все теги `<p>` нужно выполнить запрос `//p`.
Двойной слэш указывает что будет производен рекурсивный спуск по всему документу и, вне зависимости от уровня вложенности, будут выбраны теги `<p>`.

Рекомендую поставить дополнение XPatherizer в Notepad++ и поиграться.